# DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged. How fix?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, interaction, discord-buttons

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\stask\Desktop\economy koshki.fun\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\stask\Desktop\economy koshki.fun\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async ButtonInteraction.reply (C:\Users\stask\Desktop\economy koshki.fun\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:99:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/959709137103638559/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTU5NzA5MTM3MTAzNjM4NTU5OnZ0T3B6cmpWR3BxWUtiRm1CMUFlQlhvTjFnbmVTVldsM3RVSWJvZkRhdzBNN0VRcXR1RDg4Smk3Q0E3M203RFpTaWdoUHRudFNzR1BQMkJHWUg1eFFucU9xWnBsTUVQSjN5SG4yd1dleFNMeE5Ndmo1cFBZcVNYdGRyV1RtTUNO/callback',
  code: 40060,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'Ready! You closed the channel!',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: 64,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined
      }
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Code:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.customId == 'lockv') {
      if(interaction.member.roles.cache.has('892373628354711622')){
        const channelLock = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == `Voice Chat ${interaction.member.user.username}`)
       
        await channelLock.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, { 'VIEW_CHANNEL': false, 'CONNECT': false, 'SPEAK': false });
        interaction.reply({ content: 'Ready! You closed the channel!', ephemeral: true });
      }
    }
  })
```

**The purpose of my code:** Close voice by button, in a separate channel (private voice system)

**My code problem:** I made a code to close the voice, but when the bot tries to tell the creator of the channel, the console gives an error and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `await` your `interaction.reply()`.

Try the following fix:

```js
await interaction.reply({ content: 'Ready! You closed the channel!', ephemeral: true });
```

Comment: nothing SOLVED with `await` and `.then`

Comment: can you give a context of the error, and a piece of code?